# Migration from Oracle to Postgres makes query run query extremely slowly

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

we are running a script which takes Oracle about 90 seconds to execute for the same amount of records, but for Postgre it took 19 hours and 35 minutes.

This used to not be the case and the only change is the Source.

Here is our setup.
Before:
Oracle 12c is on server A. Server B has a tool that copies data from Oracle on server A to Postgre server B. Running the same query took about the same time on Oracle and on Postgre.

Now:
We updated to server C with Oracle 19. Server B stays absolutely the same and the tool only has the source changed from Server A to server C. Copy of data to Postgre is successful, the data is there. Running the same script on Oracle server C takes 90 seconds, on Postgre server B it took over 19 hours.

It is not possible to use the Postgre DB like this. Why is it happening?

The SQL query we run is the more simple one (we have another query that should also be running, but we can't work with the simpler one yet). Query is below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "AKOPF"."AUFTRAGSNUMMER", 
                "SHIERARCHIE"."EXTERNEREFERENZ7",
                (SELECT STRING_AGG(t.n, ', ' ORDER BY t.n) 
                 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT "AUFTRAGSNUMMER", 
                                       "SVERKAUFSART"."MATCHCODE" n 
                       FROM      public."ASENDUNG" ase 
                       LEFT JOIN public."SVERKAUFSART" 
                              ON ase."VERKAUFSARTID" = "SVERKAUFSART"."ID" 
                       LEFT JOIN public."AKOPF" ako 
                              ON ase."AKOPFNR"=ako."NR" 
                       WHERE "AKOPF"."NR"=ako."NR") t
                 ) OrderType,
                (SELECT MIN((CASE WHEN "ATASEND"."LADEDATUMENDEIST" IS NOT NULL 
                                  THEN "ATASEND"."LADEDATUMENDEIST" 
                                  ELSE "ATASEND"."BISLADEDATUM" 
                             END)) 
                 FROM      public."ASENDUNG"  
                 LEFT JOIN public."ATASEND" 
                        ON "ASENDUNG"."SENDUNGID" = "ATASEND"."ASENDUNGID" 
                 WHERE "ASENDUNG"."AKOPFNR" = "AKOPF"."NR" 
                 GROUP BY "AKOPF"."AUFTRAGSNUMMER") FIRSTLOADINGDATE,
                TO_CHAR((SELECT MIN((CASE WHEN "ATASEND"."LADEDATUMENDEIST" IS NOT NULL 
                                          THEN "ATASEND"."LADEDATUMENDEIST" 
                                          ELSE "ATASEND"."BISLADEDATUM" END)) 
                         FROM public."ASENDUNG"  
                         LEFT JOIN public."ATASEND" 
                                ON "ASENDUNG"."SENDUNGID" = "ATASEND"."ASENDUNGID" 
                         WHERE "ASENDUNG"."AKOPFNR" = "AKOPF"."NR" 
                         GROUP BY "AKOPF"."AUFTRAGSNUMMER"), 'IW') LOADINGWEEKCORR,
                (SELECT ROUND(SUM("ATASEND"."STATISTIKBETRAGRG")::numeric, 2) 
                 FROM public."ASENDUNG" 
                 LEFT JOIN public."ATASEND" 
                        ON "ASENDUNG"."SENDUNGID" = "ATASEND"."ASENDUNGID" 
                 WHERE "ASENDUNG"."AKOPFNR" = "AKOPF"."NR" 
                 GROUP BY "ASENDUNG"."AKOPFNR") INCOME
FROM      public."AKOPF"
LEFT JOIN public."ASENDUNG" 
       ON "ASENDUNG"."AKOPFNR"="AKOPF"."NR"
LEFT JOIN public."SHIERARCHIE" 
       ON "AKOPF"."HIERARCHIE"="SHIERARCHIE"."ID"
WHERE "ORDERTYPE"=0 
  AND "AUFTRAGSNUMMER" >1 
  AND "AKOPF"."INRECYCLEBIN"=0 
  AND "AKOPF"."ORDERTYPE"=0 
  AND "ASENDUNG"."CHECK5"=0
  AND (SELECT MIN((CASE WHEN "ATASEND"."LADEDATUMENDEIST" IS NOT NULL 
                        THEN "ATASEND"."LADEDATUMENDEIST" 
                        ELSE "ATASEND"."BISLADEDATUM" 
                   END)) 
       FROM      public."ASENDUNG"  
       LEFT JOIN public."ATASEND" 
              ON "ASENDUNG"."SENDUNGID" = "ATASEND"."ASENDUNGID" 
       WHERE "ASENDUNG"."AKOPFNR" = "AKOPF"."NR" 
       GROUP BY "AKOPF"."AUFTRAGSNUMMER") >= CURRENT_DATE - interval '4 months'
```

```html
QUERY PLAN
Unique  (cost=1551282.47..1551452.92 rows=9740 width=116) (actual time=2689.654..2702.248 rows=38130 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=1965721 read=40930 dirtied=999 written=284, temp read=242 written=242
  ->  Sort  (cost=1551282.47..1551306.82 rows=9740 width=116) (actual time=2689.653..2692.649 rows=44320 loops=1)
        Sort Key: "AKOPF"."AUFTRAGSNUMMER", "SHIERARCHIE"."EXTERNEREFERENZ7", ((SubPlan 1)), ((SubPlan 2)), (to_char(((SubPlan 3))::timestamp with time zone, 'IW'::text)), ((SubPlan 4))
        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1936kB
        Buffers: shared hit=1965721 read=40930 dirtied=999 written=284, temp read=242 written=242
        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=15879.53..1550637.21 rows=9740 width=116) (actual time=216.296..2644.036 rows=44320 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: ("AKOPF"."HIERARCHIE" = "SHIERARCHIE"."ID")
              Buffers: shared hit=1965706 read=40930 dirtied=999 written=284
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=15870.62..820869.01 rows=9740 width=24) (actual time=215.679..1131.185 rows=44320 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: ("AKOPF"."NR" = "ASENDUNG"."AKOPFNR")
                    Buffers: shared hit=281702 read=40590 dirtied=998 written=284
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on "AKOPF"  (cost=3240.61..807564.49 rows=15920 width=24) (actual time=15.483..905.518 rows=39078 loops=1)
                          Recheck Cond: (("ORDERTYPE" = 0) AND ("AUFTRAGSNUMMER" > 1))
                          Filter: (("INRECYCLEBIN" = 0) AND ((SubPlan 5) >= (CURRENT_DATE - '4 mons'::interval)))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 8026
                          Heap Blocks: exact=2713
                          Buffers: shared hit=281698 read=29369 dirtied=709 written=27
                          ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=3240.61..3240.61 rows=48069 width=0) (actual time=15.019..15.020 rows=0 loops=1)
                                Buffers: shared hit=4 read=543
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "AKOPF_I_AKOPF_MATCHCODE"  (cost=0.00..1250.87 rows=48327 width=0) (actual time=5.489..5.489 rows=47104 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: ("ORDERTYPE" = 0)
                                      Buffers: shared read=220
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "AKOPF_IX_AKOPFAUFTRAGNUMMER"  (cost=0.00..1981.53 rows=90298 width=0) (actual time=9.446..9.446 rows=87749 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: ("AUFTRAGSNUMMER" > 1)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=4 read=323
                          SubPlan 5
                            ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.58..16.64 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.017..0.017 rows=1 loops=46550)
                                  Group Key: "AKOPF"."AUFTRAGSNUMMER"
                                  Buffers: shared hit=281692 read=26115 dirtied=465 written=23
                                  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.58..16.63 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.014..0.016 rows=1 loops=46550)
                                        Buffers: shared hit=281692 read=26115 dirtied=465 written=23
                                        ->  Index Scan using "ASENDUNG_I_ASDG_AKOPFNR" on "ASENDUNG" "ASENDUNG_4"  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=1 loops=46550)
                                              Index Cond: ("AKOPFNR" = "AKOPF"."NR")
                                              Buffers: shared hit=130777 read=11689 written=9
                                        ->  Index Scan using "ATASEND_ATASENDSENDUNGID" on "ATASEND" "ATASEND_3"  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=1 loops=54049)
                                              Index Cond: ("ASENDUNG_4"."SENDUNGID" = "ASENDUNGID")
                                              Buffers: shared hit=150915 read=14426 dirtied=465 written=14
                    ->  Hash  (cost=11935.74..11935.74 rows=55542 width=8) (actual time=200.048..200.048 rows=55545 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2682kB
                          Buffers: shared hit=4 read=11221 dirtied=289 written=257
                          ->  Seq Scan on "ASENDUNG"  (cost=0.00..11935.74 rows=55542 width=8) (actual time=0.019..188.159 rows=55545 loops=1)
                                Filter: ("CHECK5" = 0)
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 1289
                                Buffers: shared hit=4 read=11221 dirtied=289 written=257
              ->  Hash  (cost=6.74..6.74 rows=174 width=16) (actual time=0.121..0.121 rows=174 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 16kB
                    Buffers: shared hit=2 read=3
                    ->  Seq Scan on "SHIERARCHIE"  (cost=0.00..6.74 rows=174 width=16) (actual time=0.012..0.087 rows=174 loops=1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=2 read=3
              SubPlan 1
                ->  Aggregate  (cost=24.98..24.99 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=1 loops=44320)
                      Buffers: shared hit=535800 read=337 dirtied=1
                      ->  Unique  (cost=24.96..24.97 rows=1 width=106) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=44320)
                            Buffers: shared hit=535800 read=337 dirtied=1
                            ->  Sort  (cost=24.96..24.96 rows=1 width=106) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=2 loops=44320)
                                  Sort Key: ako."AUFTRAGSNUMMER", "SVERKAUFSART"."MATCHCODE"
                                  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                                  Buffers: shared hit=535800 read=337 dirtied=1
                                  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.72..24.95 rows=1 width=106) (actual time=0.005..0.007 rows=2 loops=44320)
                                        Buffers: shared hit=535800 read=337 dirtied=1
                                        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.43..16.63 rows=1 width=106) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=2 loops=44320)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=300235 dirtied=1
                                              ->  Index Scan using "ASENDUNG_I_ASDG_AKOPFNR" on "ASENDUNG" ase  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=2 loops=44320)
                                                    Index Cond: ("AKOPFNR" = "AKOPF"."NR")
                                                    Buffers: shared hit=143255
                                              ->  Index Scan using "SVERKAUFSART_SVERKAUFSART_PK_SVERKAUFSART" on "SVERKAUFSART"  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=106) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=78493)
                                                    Index Cond: (ase."VERKAUFSARTID" = "ID")
                                                    Buffers: shared hit=156980 dirtied=1
                                        ->  Index Scan using "AKOPF_AKOPF_PK_AKOPF" on "AKOPF" ako  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=78493)
                                              Index Cond: ("NR" = "AKOPF"."NR")
                                              Buffers: shared hit=235565 read=337
              SubPlan 2
                ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.58..16.64 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=44320)
                      Group Key: "AKOPF"."AUFTRAGSNUMMER"
                      Buffers: shared hit=382734
                      ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.58..16.63 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.003..0.005 rows=2 loops=44320)
                            Buffers: shared hit=382734
                            ->  Index Scan using "ASENDUNG_I_ASDG_AKOPFNR" on "ASENDUNG" "ASENDUNG_1"  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=2 loops=44320)
                                  Index Cond: ("AKOPFNR" = "AKOPF"."NR")
                                  Buffers: shared hit=143255
                            ->  Index Scan using "ATASEND_ATASENDSENDUNGID" on "ATASEND"  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=78493)
                                  Index Cond: ("ASENDUNG_1"."SENDUNGID" = "ASENDUNGID")
                                  Buffers: shared hit=239479
              SubPlan 3
                ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.58..16.64 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=44320)
                      Group Key: "AKOPF"."AUFTRAGSNUMMER"
                      Buffers: shared hit=382734
                      ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.58..16.63 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.003..0.006 rows=2 loops=44320)
                            Buffers: shared hit=382734
                            ->  Index Scan using "ASENDUNG_I_ASDG_AKOPFNR" on "ASENDUNG" "ASENDUNG_2"  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=2 loops=44320)
                                  Index Cond: ("AKOPFNR" = "AKOPF"."NR")
                                  Buffers: shared hit=143255
                            ->  Index Scan using "ATASEND_ATASENDSENDUNGID" on "ATASEND" "ATASEND_1"  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=78493)
                                  Index Cond: ("ASENDUNG_2"."SENDUNGID" = "ASENDUNGID")
                                  Buffers: shared hit=239479
              SubPlan 4
                ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.58..16.65 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=44320)
                      Group Key: "ASENDUNG_3"."AKOPFNR"
                      Buffers: shared hit=382734
                      ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.58..16.63 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.003..0.005 rows=2 loops=44320)
                            Buffers: shared hit=382734
                            ->  Index Scan using "ASENDUNG_I_ASDG_AKOPFNR" on "ASENDUNG" "ASENDUNG_3"  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=2 loops=44320)
                                  Index Cond: ("AKOPFNR" = "AKOPF"."NR")
                                  Buffers: shared hit=143255
                            ->  Index Scan using "ATASEND_ATASENDSENDUNGID" on "ATASEND" "ATASEND_2"  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=78493)
                                  Index Cond: ("ASENDUNG_3"."SENDUNGID" = "ASENDUNGID")
                                  Buffers: shared hit=239479
Planning time: 12.763 ms
Execution time: 2706.773 ms
```

Comment: For postgresql performance related questions please add the query plan: `explain (analyse, buffers)`

Comment: Most probably you lost an index(es) in the migration and you are looping a `Seq scan` on a large table. A definitive answer will show the *execution plan*. Run only `explain()` to *not wait an other 19h 35m*

Comment: Apart from Marmite's comment I agree with, I've noticed you go joining through the same tables several times, and you stick subqueries over subqueries, together with several aggregations. Was wondering that this code may be even simplifiable, although such kind of operation would require sample tables for tables employed by this query, corresponding expected output, and a description of what this query should actually do.

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber what should I do with the information from EXPLAIN? It loaded information, but I am not sure how that helps me.

Comment: Post the result of the `explain` in the edited question

Comment: Explain only shows the query plan, no details no results and hardly any useful information. Always use explain (analyze, verbose, buffers)

Comment: @MarmiteBomber, Edited with the result of explain (analyze, verbose, buffers)

Comment: `Execution time: 2706.773 ms` this does not correspond to a query running `19 hours 35 mimutes`

Comment: @MarmiteBomber, You know thing just started working on its own. The query took 19 hours to complete. Today, it takes a couple of seconds. I have absolutely no idea how and why it fixed itself, but now it works even faster than before refreshing the data... Thank you for the help.